# Pandas merge filling new dataframe with null values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, null

I am trying to merge two dataframes:

- The first dataframe, `control`, is filled with **INTEGERS/STRINGS**
- The left dataframe, together, is filled with **INTEGERS/LISTS**.

When I use the pandas `merge()` function, the new dataframe **fills the right dataframe with NaN,** rather than the lists

```
final_dataset = pd.merge(control, together, on="zip_code", how="left")
```

I expect a new merged dataframe with the values from the two original dataframes. Instead, in the new dataframe, all of the values from the "control" dataframe are correct but all of lists from the "together" dataframe are NaN

Here is some sample data:

```
control                                       together
-------------------------------              -------------------------------
payment             zip_code                   age                  zip_code
   Rent                 94053                    [25, 64, 24]         12583
   Mortgage             47283                    [78. 39, 35]         47283
   Rent                 25769                    [82, 33, 19]         25769
```

Here is what the final dataset looks like:

```
final_dataset
-----------------------------------------------------------
zip_code             payment                 age                  
47283                  Mortgage               NaN                 
25769                  Rent                   NaN
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Comment: When you perform an inner join `how='inner'` do you get any value? It could be that the ids are not matching.

Comment: Use `pd.concat` with `axis=1` if both dataframes are identically indexed.

Comment: you provided code with merging `on='zip_codes'`, but in your sample data there is no `zip_codes` variable. Also, please keep your sample data separate so that it would be easier for us to replicate

Comment: @iuvbio added some sample code

Comment: @politicalscientist added zip_codes, sorry!

Comment: @minanmafi you should check using `pd.merge(control, together, on="zip_code", how="inner")` whether you get any results and add that to the question. If there are none, then your `zip_code` values are not actually the same.

Comment: If zip_code is a string column, check to see that the strings don't have leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: Please provide output of `control.zip_code.dtype` and `together.zip_code.dtype`

Comment: Almost surely because `zip_code` is a string/float/int64(/Categorical) in one dataframe, and a different type in the other, as people are suggesting. But I'm surprised pandas just silently does the wrong thing, without a warning. This seems like a good catch for a bug.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have a few things going on here.  When you say the left dataframe I assume that you mean that it should be the left joined right?  You don't mean that 'together' is on the left side in the sample?

I think it is safe to assume that your zip_code in 'together' is a string not an 'int'. You are getting the NaN's because they do not match in the 2 dataframes example 47283 does not equal '47283'.

Also, if it's a left join you want with together being on the left you should have 1 NaN on payment since you only have 2 zip_codes that match if they are the same datatype.

Here is how I would recommend doing it if you want control on the left (I think you do):

```py
control = pd.DataFrame({
    'payment':['Rent','Mortgage','Rent'],
    'zip_code':[94053,47283,25769]
})
together = pd.DataFrame({
    'age':[[25,64,24],[78, 39,35],[82,33,19]],
    'zip_code':[12583,47283,25769]
})

control.merge(together,on='zip_code',how='left')
```

This will give you the following results:

```
    payment  zip_code           age
0      Rent     94053           NaN
1  Mortgage     47283  [78, 39, 35]
2      Rent     25769  [82, 33, 19]
```

As you can see you have 1 NaN in age as 94053 is not in the 'together' DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

This could happens if the zip_code columns have different types for each dataframe, may be one of them is int64, and the other is object and for eg:

```
 a = pd.DataFrame([
    {"colA": 1, "key": "1"},
    {"colA": 2, "key": "2"},
    {"colA": 3, "key": "3"}
])

b = pd.DataFrame([
    {"colB": [25, 64, 24], "key": 1},
    {"colB": [25, 64, 24], "key": 2},
    {"colB": [25, 64, 24], "key": 4}
])
```

if you merge this two dataframe, you'll get

```
res = pd.merge(a, b, on="key", how='left')



   colA key colB
0   1   1   NaN
1   2   2   NaN
2   3   3   NaN
```

So you need to make sur that zip_code has the same type in the two dataframes.